# Multisite Installation (Attempt) Goes To My Main Site

Tags: multi-sites, .htaccess

I am attempting to perform a multisite installation. My main (presently working) site is located in a subdirectory called "beta" of my ~/public_html folder. This is the site for jackstahlco.com and it is working. I also want to have this installation of Drupal run two other sites.

The first other site I am trying to get to work is meadowlarknm.com. This site is presently resolving to jackstahlco.com, which is NOT correct. I created ~/public_html/beta/sites/meadowlarknm.com/ and ~/public_html/beta/sites/meadowlarknm.com/files. I copied default.settings.php into meadowlardnm.com/ and changed the permissions, as well as creating a 'files' directory. The settings.php also contains

```
$databases = array ();
```

and no other database configuration.

When I navigate to www.meadowlarknm.com, I just see the www.jackstahlco.com website, instead of the Drupal installation screen that I expect. You can go there to see what I'm talking about, unless I fix this problem immediately after writing this question.

I am suspecting that this may be a .htaccess issue, but I am not sure. It's a little bit weird that I am trying to run multi-site from a subdirectory, but it seems like this should be possible (if my understanding was complete.)

Here is my .htaccess (inside ~/public_html, I did NOT change the .htaccess inside ~/public_html/beta):

```
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.jackstahlco\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.jackstahlco.com/      [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ beta/index.php   [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/beta%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* beta/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* beta/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
#
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?jackstahlco.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /beta/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?jackstahlcompany.com/puertadelsolsite$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ puertadelsolsite [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meadowlarknm\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.meadowlarknm.com/$1 [L,R=301]

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) index.php
#RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
 suPHP_ConfigPath /home/jsco
 <Files php.ini>
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
 </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Additionally, the following is in /home/jsco/public_html/beta/sites/sites.php:

```
  $sites = array(
   'www.jackstahlco.com' => 'default',
   'www.meadowlarknm.com' => 'meadowlarknm.com',
  );
```

The end goal here is to re-do the existing sites on this server (some Joomla! as you may have guessed from the .htaccess) to a single Drupal system running multisite.

I don't believe this is a DNS issue. nslookup says these are all going to the correct place, and my domain-to-folder mapping on cPanel (sending everything to ~/public_html) looks OK.

Additionally, the multisite wizard says MOST of my steps are OK.

```
OK Create sites/sites.php file
OK Fill up sites/sites.php file with domain-folder array
OK Create sites folders inside sites/ folder
OK Each site folder should have own settings.php file
NOT OK - Prefix inside each settings.php file should be unique. I think I want a different DB
```

Thank you very much for the help.

-Brian J. Stinar-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed this is not a DNS issue, the problem here is your `sites` directory is located in the wrong directory. It shouldn't be under `all` but in the root of `sites`. In your case it should be:

```
sites/jackstahlco.com/settings.php
sites/jackstahlco.com/files
sites/meadowlarknm.com/settings.php
sites/meadowlarknm.com/files
```

If you want the Drupal installation process popping up, you need to put an empty array connection info in the settings.php of the desired website.

```
$databases = array ();
```

The `sites.php` should be like this:

```
$sites = array(
    'jackstahlco.com' => 'default',
    'meadowlarknm.com' => 'meadowlarknm.com',
);
```

You don't need to specify the `www` prefix.